Splitting a Number into Random Parts
I am trying to simulate 4 random numbers that sum to 100.
My original ideas the following:

Generate $x$:
$$
   x \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 100)
$$

Generate $ y $:
$$
   y \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 100 - x)
$$

Generate $ z $:
$$
   z \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 100 - x - y)
$$

Generate $ w $:
$$
   w \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 100 - x - y - z)
$$

Sum of the four numbers:
$$
   \text{Sum} = x + y + z + w \leq 100
$$


However, I realized that there is no guarantee that these 4 numbers will sum to 100!
I saw this an R simulation:


Is there a better way to do this? Can the Dirichlet Distribution be used? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)

The distributions over $x, y, z, w$ in this approach are also wildly asymmetric. It would be easier to generate $x, y, z, w, \sim U(0, 100)$, or anything else, then normalize their sum to $100$; that would at least guarantee symmetry. The Dirichlet distribution could also be used and would also guarantee symmetry. It depends on what you're trying to model.

Does random number mean integer? And does "random numbers sum to 100" mean  you are looking for a uniform distribution of tuples among all tuples that sum to 100?

To sample four random numbers summing to $100$, you can use the Dirichlet distribution with $k=4$ and $\alpha=(1,1,1,1)$.  Here is an easy way to sample from this distribution, according to wikipedia.

First, choose three numbers $A_1,A_2,A_3\sim \text{Uniform}(0,100)$, independently.

Let $B_1,B_2,B_3$ be the result of sorting $A_1,A_2,A_3$ in increasing order. So, $B_1=\min(A_1,A_2,A_3),B_2=\text{median}(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ and $B_3=\text{max}(A_1,A_2,A_3)$.

Finally, define
$$
X=B_1,\quad Y=B_2-B_1,\quad Z=B_3-B_2,\quad W=100-B_3.
$$


Clearly, $X+Y+Z+W=100$ always. You can check that $X,Y,Z,$ and $W$ all have the same probability distribution. The common cdf of these four random variables is
$$
F(x)=P(X\le x)=1-(1-x/100)^3.
$$

Here is a complicated method to accomplish the same task. We will choose four numbers $X,Y,Z,W$ such that $X+Y+Z+W=2$ always, and such that each variable has the same distribution. This time, the common distribution will be uniform, $X\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$. If you then scale up everything by a factor of $50$, you then get four random variables summing to $100$, where each is uniform on $(0,50)$.
Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$ be the sequence of base-$4$ digits of $X$. This means that $x_i\in \{0,1,2,3\}$ for each $i\in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$, and that $X=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i\cdot (1/4)^i$.  Define $y_i,z_i,$ and $w_i$ similarly. We are going to choose $X,Y,Z,W$ by simultaneously choosing all of the base-$4$ digits of all four variables.
The idea is that, for each $i\ge 1$, the $4$-tuple of digits $(x_i,y_i,z_i,w_i)$ will be chosen uniformly from the $4!$ permutations of $(0,1,2,3)$. Note that $X$ will be $\text{Unif}(0,1)$, because $X$ has uniformly random base-$4$ digits. Furthermore, it will always be the case that
$$
X+Y+Z+W=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (0+1+2+3)(1/4)^i=6\times \frac{1/4}{1-1/4}=2.
$$

I was about to post a similar answer, but I won't now given this. The only change in my idea was to have $A1,A2,A3,A4$ and $B1,B2,B3,B4$ and define $X=(B1-B4)$ modulo $100$ and $W=B4-B3$. $Y$ and $Z$ would be the same as yours

+1 Note that if you want four positive integers which sum to $100$ then you should choose $A_1,A_2,A_3$ from ${1,2,\ldots, 99}$ without replacement - so not quite independent of each other.

@ Mike : thank you so much! Do you know if we can use the Dirichlet Probability Distribution to simulate these numbers?

You can only generate 3 of the 4 numbers, since you also have a constraint on the sum. Your best bet is to sample $x$, $y$ and $z$ from $U(0,100)$ and then define $w = 400 - (x+y+z)$, and divide each of the obtained numbers by $4$

$w$ will be biased high in this process as the expected sum of $x,y,z$ is $150$.
